# Async Task method WaitingForActivation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

I have found a very confusing behavior of `async` methods. Consider the following Console app:

```
private static int _i = 0;
private static Task<int> _calculateTask = Task.FromResult(0);
private static int _lastResult = 0;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Calculate());
    }
}

private static int Calculate()
{
    if (!_calculateTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        return _lastResult;
    }

    _lastResult = _calculateTask.Result;
    _calculateTask = CalculateNextAsync();
    return _lastResult;
}

private static async Task<int> CalculateNextAsync()
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return ++_i;
    });
}
```

As expected, after it is launched, it first prints out a bunch of 0s, then ones, twos and so on.

In contrast consider the following UWP app snippet:

```
private static int _i = 0;
private static Task<int> _calculateTask = Task.FromResult(0);
private static int _lastResult = 0;
public int Calculate()
{
    if (!_calculateTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        return _lastResult;
    }

    _lastResult = _calculateTask.Result;
    _calculateTask = CalculateNextAsync();
    return _lastResult;
}

private static async Task<int> CalculateNextAsync()
{
    return await Task.Run( async() =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        return ++_i;
    });
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    while( true)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(Calculate());
    }
}
```

Although these two differ only in one small detail, the UWP snippet just keeps printing out 0 and task state in the `if` statement just stays `Waitingforactivation`. Furthermore the problem can be fixed by removing `async` and `await` from `CalculateNextAsync`:

```
private static Task<int> CalculateNextAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        return ++_i;
    });
}
```

Now everything works the same way as in the Console app.

Can someone explain the reason why the behavior in Console differs from UWP app? And why the task stays as `c` in case of UWP app?

## Update

I have got back to this question again, but found out an issue that the originally accepted answer does not cover - the code on UWP *never reaches* the `.Result`, it just keeps checking for `IsCompleted` which returns `false`, hence the `_lastResult` is returned. What makes the `Task` have a `AwaitingActivation` state when it should have completed?

### Solution

I figured out that the reason is that the active waiting `while` loop prevents the `await` continuation from ever seizing the UI thread again, hence causing a "deadlock"-like situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the code in the UWP app there is no need for holding on to the `_calculateTask`. Just `await` the task.

Here is the updated code

```
private static int _i = 0;
private static int _lastResult = 0;

public async Task<int> Calculate() {    
    _lastResult = await CalculateNextAsync();
    return _lastResult;
}

//No need to wrap the code in a Task.Run. Just await the async code
private static async Task<int> CalculateNextAsync()  
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    return ++_i;
}

//Event Handlers allow for async void
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    while( true) {
        var result = await Calculate();
        Debug.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

---

## ORIGINAL ANSWER

You are mixing async/await and blocking calls like `.Result` in the UWP app which is causing a deadlock because of its one chunk SynchronizationContext. Console applications are an exception to that rule, which is why it works there and not in the UWP app.

> The root cause of this deadlock is due to the way await handles
> contexts. By default, when an incomplete Task is awaited, the current
> “context” is captured and used to resume the method when the Task
> completes. This “context” is the current SynchronizationContext unless
> it’s null, in which case it’s the current TaskScheduler. GUI and
> ASP.NET applications have a SynchronizationContext that permits only
> one chunk of code to run at a time. When the await completes, it
> attempts to execute the remainder of the async method within the
> captured context. But that context already has a thread in it, which
> is (synchronously) waiting for the async method to complete. They’re
> each waiting for the other, causing a deadlock.
>
> Note that console applications don’t cause this deadlock. They have a
> thread pool SynchronizationContext instead of a one-chunk-at-a-time
> SynchronizationContext, so when the await completes, it schedules the
> remainder of the async method on a thread pool thread. The method is
> able to complete, which completes its returned task, and there’s no
> deadlock. This difference in behavior can be confusing when
> programmers write a test console program, observe the partially async
> code work as expected, and then move the same code into a GUI or
> ASP.NET application, where it deadlocks.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for the clear explanation!

Comment: I have got back to this question again, but found out an problem - the code on UWP *never reaches* the `.Result`, it just keeps checking for `IsCompleted`. Why is that?

Comment: Oh, I understand now, the reason is that the `while` loop never allows the continuation to seize the UI thread which makes it "basically" deadlocked.